# Certificate Signing

Tags: digital-certificate

I know that in RSA algorithm a Public key is used to ecrypt data which can be decrypted using only the private key.

When a digital certificate is signed the hash of the certificate is signed using the private key of the RootCA and during validation the public key is used to verify the hash. In this case signing means encrypting. Also, sha1RSA algorithm is one of the algos used for signing a certificate.

Thus private key used for Encryption and public key used for Decrytion of the Hash ? 
Is this possible using RSA or I understood wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite logical. Private key is known only by owner and public key is known by everyone.

When doing asynchronous encryption, it's important that everyone can produce encrypted message (by using public key), but only recipient (private key holder) will be able to read the message.

When doing digital signatures, it's important that everyone can verify signature (by using public key), but only creator (private key holder) will be able to produce it.